# How to comment from the start of the line in makefile-mode?

Tags: comment, makefile-mode

If one highlights a tab-indented line in `makefile-mode` and runs a comment function (eg. `comment-dwim`, `comment-line`, `comment-region`, etc.), the comment symbol (`#`) is inserted after the initial tab, like so:

```
target:
    # echo This "commented" line will be passed to the shell
```

As explained in [this illuminating answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7738/7189), Make does not recognise this line as a comment, and the line will be passed to the Shell to interpret on its own terms. `makefile-mode` helpfully highlights the leading tab to alert us.

What would be the simplest way to alter the behaviour of Emacs for Makefiles, so that for whole lines within the region the inbuilt comment functions cause the comment symbol to be added at the very start of the line, creating true Makefile comments, rather than shell comments?

Comment: Insert a new line starting with `#` above the region you need to comment, then select the region together with that new line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'cause' of this behavior is mentioned in the docstring of e.g. `comment-region`.

You can simply adjust the behavior by configuring the `comment-style`, e.g. using:

```lisp
(add-hook 'makefile-gmake-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq-local comment-style 'plain)))
```

Read the docstring of `comment-styles` for more info.